# How to set a default value in <v-select>?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this select here:

```
<v-select px-4 class='select'
      v-model="form.accountType"
      :items="accountTypes"
      :label="$t('form.accountType')"
      :rules="[rules.required, rules.validAccountType]"
      color= 'primary'
      ></v-select>
```

I want the select initialice with one of the items of the select:

```
accountTypes () {
  const types = [
    {
      value: 'business',
      text: this.$t('form.accountTypeBusiness')
    },
    {
      value: 'personal',
      text: this.$t('form.accountTypePersonal')
    }
  ]
  return types
}
```

I've passed a  with this prop:

```
form: {
    accountType: 'Personal'
}
```

but the `v-model` doesn't work. Is there any way to set `Personal` as a default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value is case sensitive so start it with a small letter since the value in array is starts with small letter.

```
form: {
   accountType: 'personal'
   // -----------^--------
}
```